# Regex to extract three characters

Tags: r, regex

I have the following string:

```
str <- "add2AHJJK_GLX_KLKNKMEMa13"
```

How can I use R to extract "GLX" from it, the word between the underscores? In the example, there are exactly two underscores, not more.

Comment: `sub(".*_(.*)_.*", "\\1", str)`

Comment: Is the string guaranteed to have exactly two non-adjacent underscores? I am wondering about  `"J_KG_LX_KL"` (two matches?), `"JK__GLX_KL"` (one match or two matches, the first empty?), `"JK_KL"` (no match or an empty match?) and `"JKL"` (no match?).

Comment: @CarySwoveland good point, I actually just realized there is another string with multiple underscores. That makes it more complicated I guess. There are however no cases with multiple underscores in a row ("__").

Comment: Since questions have been posted that assume there are exactly two underscores, perhaps you should edit to state that is the case, and then post a separate if you want to generalize. btw, this illustrates the ambiguity that often results when a question is expressed in terms of a single example. I believe questions should be expressed in words with examples used only for illustration. That's generally more difficult and time-consuming, but it's a skill demanded by the workplace.

Comment: By defining unambiguous rules, you are well on the way to able to code the appropriate regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option with `gsub` to match characters that are not a `_` (`[^_]*`) from the start (`^`) of the string to the `_` or (`|`) characters from `_` to the rest and replace with blank (`""`)

```
gsub("^[^_]*_|_.*", "", str)
#[1] "GLX"
```

---

Or another option is extraction with `regexpr/regmatches`

```
regmatches(str, regexpr('(?<=_)\\w+(?=_)', str, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "GLX"
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's always just the middle of three parts between "_"s we can.

```r
library(stringr)

str_split(str, "_", simplify = TRUE)[[2]]
[1] "GLX"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` to extract a word between underscores.

```
sub('.*_(\\w+)_.*', '\\1', str)
#[1] "GLX"
```

Or `str_match` :

```
stringr::str_match(str, '_(\\w+)_')[, 2]
```